# DirectShow push sources, syncing and timestamping

Tags: filter, push, directshow

I have a filter graph that takes raw audio and video input and then uses the ASF Writer to encode them to a WMV file.

I've written two custom push source filters to provide the input to the graph. The audio filter just uses WASAPI in loopback mode to capture the audio and send the data downstream. The video filter takes raw RGB frames and sends them downstream.

For both the audio and video frames, I have the performance counter value for the time the frames were captured.

**Question 1:** If I want to properly timestamp the video and audio, do I need to create a custom reference clock that uses the performance counter or is there a better way for me to sync the two inputs, i.e. calculate the stream time?

The video input is captured from a Direct3D buffer somewhere else and I cannot guarantee the framerate, so it behaves like a live source. I always know the start time of a frame, of course, but how do I know the end time?

For instance, let's say the video filter ideally wants to run at 25 FPS, but due to latency and so on, frame 1 starts perfectly at the 1/25th mark but frame 2 starts later than the expected 2/25th mark. That means there's now a gap in the graph since the end time of frame 1 doesn't match the start time of frame 2.

**Question 2:** Will the downstream filters know what to do with the delay between frame 1 and 2, or do I manually have to decrease the length of frame 2?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think video frames do not have an end time, (or an end time which is always 1 ms after the start). This is because a video frame is just a sample of a moment in time. So I asume gaps are not a problem for video.

Answer (score 1):

1. One option is to omit time stamps, but this might end up in filters fail to process this data. Another option is to use [`System Reference Clock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to generate time stamps - in any way this is preferable to directly using performance counter as a time stamp source.

   1. Yes you need to time stamp video and audio in order to keep them in sync, this is the only way to tell that data is actually attributed to the same time
   2. Video samples don't have time, you can omit stop time or set it equal to start time, a gap between video frame stop time and next frame start time has no consequences
2. Renderers are free to choose whether they need to respect time stamps or not, with audio you of course will want smooth stream without gaps in time stamps

Comment: 1. If the two input sources are different (which they are), I still need a common clock in order to sync them. I guess I could calculate the start time manually from the performance counter and pass the value to my two input filters via a custom interface. At least I'd be able to to use that when calculating the stream time. Either way, I'm forced to use the performance counter as the capture time since that's what e.g. WASAPI gives me back and the video frame is captured in another process, so I need something that's system-wide. Unless you have a better idea?

Comment: 2. So would it be better if I capture a little faster than the target FPS so I know I won't have potential gaps?

Comment: 1. Performance counter is not accurate and accumulates error. `System Reference Clock` is accurate, its precision is smaller, but still sufficient. 2. Capture to reach target FPS, I don't see how making it faster actually might make things better.

Comment: 1. So, how do I sync the two streams then? When I push a new frame to the video input filter, if I use the filter reference time at that time it won't match the time the frame was actually captured since there's a significant delay between capturing the frame and delivering it to the input filter. On the other hand, the audio input has a lot shorter latency and I'm therefore afraid the two streams will be out of sync.